# Are Terminator robots able to have sex?

Tags: character, terminator-series

Can Terminator robots (not the liquid ones) have sex with humans?

As per Terminator Wiki in

> *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* **Cameron Model - T-900** is an advanced model and is admittedly different than all other robots.

Does that mean she's capable of having sex? Otherwise, is it mentioned in any Terminator movies that terminator robots had sex with humans because of their missions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vick Chamberlain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Terminator:_The_Sarah_Connor_Chronicles_characters#Vick_Chamberlain), a terminator from the **Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles** TV series, poses as a husband of city manager Barbara Chamberlain. He/it was sent back in time to help create a traffic surveillance network that Skynet hopes to use in the future.

> (John and Cameron are watching a playback of Vick's memory)
>
> Barbara: Vick, god, you poor thing. You're up again? I told you, just take one of my pills. Fine, babe, come back to bed. I can't sleep with you standing there like a statue.
>
> John Connor: Was that thing... Married?
>
> Cameron: The T-triple 8 is an advanced model infiltrator.
>
> John Connor: Yeah, but I don't think she knows. I mean, is that possible?
>
> Cameron: She would not be the first human fooled by a machine.

The above transcript, form the [1x08 Vick's Chip](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_108:_Vick%27s_Chip) episode, states that the infiltrator models were exceptional at deceiving humans.

> is it mentioned in any Terminator movies that terminator robots had sex with humans because of their missions?

I would say it's implied.

Comment: your example is good..but do you remember after this some other scene she's saying " I know i'v bean working a lot, & I know its hard for you hanging around at home, since your car accident i thought we may progress.." so this means Triple 8 killed Barbara husband & replaced by Triple 8 this innceiden happned after Barbara's merrage. ..so from this example how can we say this terminator had sex with Barbara Chamberlain

Comment: @RANSARA009 Yeah, It's been a while since I've watched the series, so I might be missing some details. It may be just my general impression of the whole story - Triple 8 replacing Barbara's husband, and successfully deceiving her for quite a while. I think that involves intimacy with ones wife, but I'm not married so I might be wrong ;)

Comment: @bartosz, no worry's man.. you are the only person have some kind of answer for the question..thank you so much for that.. :-)